# Insert values for all 2nd columns of a 1st column of a 2D array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to do what the question says. (It might be confusing)
Here is some code that should make you understand what I'm trying to do.

```
classes = new string[14, 5];
classes[0] = {"Value1 [0, 0]", "Value2 [0, 1]", "Value3 [0, 2]", "Value4 [0, 3]", "Value5 [0, 4]"};
```

Comment: 2nd column of 1st column?? Do you mean 2nd column of 1st row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some languages or environments(like Matlab) allow such things to work, but C# doesn't provide such access for rectangular arrays String[x, y].

With such arrays you should change each element individually:

```
String[,] classes = new string[14, 5];classes = new string[14, 5];

Int32 rowToChange = 0;

for(Int32 col = 0; col < classes.GetLength(1); col++)
{
   classes[rowToChange, col] = String.Format("Value{0} [{1}. {0}]", rowToChange , col  );
}
```

But you could use jagged arrays : String[][]

```
String[][] classes = new string[14][];

Int32 rowToChange = 0;

classes[rowToChange] = new String[]{"Value1 [0, 0]", "Value2 [0, 1]", "Value3 [0, 2]", "Value4 [0, 3]", "Value5 [0, 4]"};
```

You could read [What are the differences between a multidimensional array and an array of arrays in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-are-the-differences-between-a-multidimensional-array-and-an-array-of-arrays) to understand the differences

Comment: Thx, why does this fail? "classes = new string[14][5];" Same with "String". (Code inline/blocks not supported for comments?)

Comment: Don't know. My snippets work - try them. Maybe the type of 'classes'(how you defined it?) is incorrect.

Comment: Thx man! Your solution of jagged arrays worked! I read the link as well and it turns out that jagged arrays are faster too! Best answer selected :)